# AWS cloudformation - get substring

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I just start to use AWS cloudformation and I got a block as below:

I have a string

```
string = redundant_value/12b4/xyz/succes
```

And I want to get `12b4/xyz/succes` of the string. How would I get it?

[image: my illustration here]

Another example for my question:

```
${string} = abcd/123xx/OBcs/azy_cd
```

how would I get only `123xx/OBcs/azy_cd` from ${string}

Can I do this?

```
fn::Split: ['abcd/', ${string}] = [123xx/OBcs/azy_cd]
fn::Select: [0, [123xx/OBcs/azy_cd]]
```

I have read there is a method about `Fn::Sub`. But I am not able to understand it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Split](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-split.html) and [Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-select.html) on condition that the first part (`abcd`) is **constant**:

```
Resources:

    NullResource:
        Type: AWS::CloudFormation::WaitConditionHandle
        Properties: {}
        
Outputs:

    Test:
        Value: !Select [1, !Split ["abcd/", "abcd/123xx/OBcs/azy_cd"]]
```

[image]

Comment: If I !Splict[!Split ["/",your_string]], it would return array [redundant_value,12b4,xyz,succes] your result would return '12b4' right?. So it is not correct for this case, the result I wannt get result = 12b4/xyz/succes

Comment: @BrianHuynh Not sure what do you mean. Your code is invalid CloudFormation. I would suggest editing your question with actual, working and valid CFN template that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Sorry, for my bad asking question. So let me explain again as below:
${string} = abcd/123xx/OBcs/azy_cd
how would I get only 123xx/OBcs/azy_cd from ${string}
Can I do this?
fn::Split: ['abcd/', ${string}] = [123xx/OBcs/azy_cd]
fn::Select: [0, [123xx/OBcs/azy_cd]]
Thank you

Comment: @BrianHuynh How many slashes `/` is there? Always 3?

Comment: no, it would be multiple slashes like xyz/abc/../.../value

Comment: @BrianHuynh And the `redundant_value` (the first value), is constant or not?

Comment: yes, it is a  constant

Comment: @BrianHuynh I updated the answer with **working** example.